# Difference between "stumble up to" and "stumble to"?

Tags: difference

I have a question on an expression "verb + up to".

In the following sentences, which one is better?

> He stumbled to a woman in the bar.
>
> He stumbled up to a woman in the bar.

what is the subtle difference between them?

Comment: Arguably the second is better. Both imply the person in question was drunk. The first appears to sound a bit off, but is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Up** with verbs of motion conveys the idea of reaching the destination.

**He walked up to the house and knocked on the door.**

The house does not have to be on a hill.  Walking "up" to a house means to walk all the way to it.

So, to a shy friend, you might say:

**Go ahead, walk up to her and introduce yourself.**

In your example, if you want to convey the idea that he made his way to the woman, reaching the point where he was facing her, within conversation distance, you'd say

**He stumbled up to a woman at the bar.**

(or "in the bar" -- "at" means she is near the counter where drinks are served; "in" means somewhere in the room).